# Where can I find an up-to-date list of COVID-19-related curfews and business closures in different countries?

Tags: online-resources, covid-19

Where can I find an up-to-date list of COVID-19-related curfews and business closures in different countries? I find it challenging to stay up-to-date.

---

Note to the close voters: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm is a great list regarding travel restrictions for all countries in the world. I don't see why a similar list for COVID-19-related curfews and business closures couldn't exist, and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_related_curfews_and_lockdowns is one example of an attempt of it.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNvHJM)
- [Reddit](https://redd.it/fqgo8x)
- [Reddit 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/travel/comments/fjhjoz/coronavirus_megathread_for_travelrelated/flqb6oj/)

Comment: @Willeke noted. I think where else I posted the question is relevant so that answerers are aware of other anwers.  Also for Quora I'm partly doing this to avoid [Quora users (bots?) are copying a significant amount of Stack Exchange questions to Quora, without proper attribution (duplicate)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342516/178179).

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt Are you looking for a complete list globally? Or specific regions / countries? Eg for the UK https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/876535/270320_Revised_Guidance.pdf

Comment: @Traveller  complete list globally, so that we don't have to have 1 question per regions / countries.

Comment: This would be difficult to do since it changes every day. Best you probably could do is to create a list of links to official websites for each country/state/county/region. That's unlikely to happen since there are so many of them.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I dare to say: there is none. And if one existed, it would be outdated within hours. Even 'official' resources like Timatic does not manage to keep up to date on travel and border crossing restrictions. A word-wide list of curfews and business closures will in reality be impossible to compile.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo apparently this one, see the answer. It might need frequent updates but it's better than nothing, and anyone can update the list.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: You could say the same abut IATA, about Timatic, or even about travel agencies. Yet such things do exist. It's a bit like saying "news sites are impossible on the internet because the news changes every day".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Wikipedia has a page on COVID-19 related curfews and lockdowns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_related_curfews_and_lockdowns (thanks [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) for pointing to that resource).
- [Dataset on coronavirus government countermeasures (per country/region/city?)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/16244/1652)
- The websites of the local US embassies often mention nationwide or local curfews, and seem to be quite frequently updated, e.g. https://mx.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/covid-19-information/, https://do.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/
  https://ht.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information, https://ec.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information-ecu-2/

Comment: This list is just a very broad overview and of no practical use to anyone actually affected by the restrictions. It does not for a single country tell what is allowed and what not.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo depends on which country. Some country does have some extensive information such as India. Also anyone can edit the wikpedia page, so you can view this answer as an improvable, editable wiki answer hosted on Wikipedia.

Comment: Link-only answers are usually not suitable here. To quote from the help center: *Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.* I also find it very unlikely that the Wikipedia page can be kept up to date and especially in this situation, I would consider lack of information better than wrong or outdated information. We've already had several wrong answers here on the site based on quoted information, wich is just a few days old. That is not what people need right now.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo have you seen the online-resource tag the question? This means that OP is looking for online resources, which typically come under the form of a URL.