# What (if any) countries are either open to or have set definitive plans to allow international tourism?

Tags: international-travel, covid-19, travel-ban

Around mid-March 2020, most countries entered some form of lock down in an effort to contain outbreaks of the novel coronavirus (nCov-19). As part of these lock downs, most forms of tourism were disallowed due through a variety of mechanisms such as visitor bans on non-citizens/non-residents, quarantines for incoming international travelers and hotel shutdowns.  Since the beginning of May 2020, these lock down measures have been successful in reducing active COVID-19 caseloads in some places resulting in plans to lift previous COVID-19 restrictions.

The question is: **Which countries have allowed or set concrete plans to allow inbound international tourism?** In order to qualify, all the following criteria must be met:

1. Individuals who are not citizens or residents of that country may be granted entry for tourism purposes.
2. Individuals who arrive from abroad are not required to spend a full 14 days in quarantine once arriving because one of the following applies:

   - no inbound quarantine obligation exists
   - certain international locations are exempt from quarantine obligations
   - tourists are exempt from quarantine measures
   - quarantine obligations can be removed upon testing negative for COVID-19
   - etc
3. Basic touristic services such as hotels or other overnight accommodation services are permitted to operate. (Although many popular tourist attractions may be closed due to crowd/hygine restrictions.)
4. There exist reasonable mechanisms that allow international travelers to come to the country.
5. There are no other obvious hindrances which block pragmatic international tourism.

Comment: Not sure if it's a good question here - stuff with COVID-19 restrictions changes every day. Answer provided today has a high change to be outdated tomorrow.

Comment: (+1) I think the question is fine, even if the answer will probably be “none” at the moment (but it could be updated later). But isn't called “SARS-CoV-2“ instead of “nCov-19” now?

Comment: The reopening of external borders for non- essential travel is at present a **very low** priority and will probably remain so until some form of vaccine exists. The relatively  unrestricted travel (i.e. other than immigration) that existed before 2020 will probably not be resumed. When serious thoughts are maded on this matter, casual travel (tourism) will probably remain a low priority. Such thoughts will probably only start after the next winter season, after a possible 2nd (and possibility 3rd) wave.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's actually not true. Tourism is very high on the list of priorities for the many regions and countries that depend on it economically. It's more difficult to revive, which is the main reason it will take longer, but there is no reason it should be considered intrinsically less important than car factories, fashion stores, restaurants or hairdressers and I would be very surprised if nothing is attempted (even foolishly) long before a vaccine is widely available. It's certainly already being discussed.

Comment: @Relaxed The problem is the **how**, not the wanting to. The problem is at the moment that during the first 2 weeks no reliable test exists to determine that someone is infected (thus the 2 week quarantine at present). This is the main problem and will remain so until a vaccine exists. Also the immunity of previously effected peaple is not yet clear. There are reports that they are still carriers (i.e. the virus is still in their system and can be passed on). Until these things are clarified mass travel will be difficult. A 2 week quarantine for tourists is unreasonable.

Comment: @MarkJohnson How is a very big problem, just as it is for many other things. I agree with that, I wrote as much in my earlier comment. But, for better or for worse, I fully expect some countries to try to compromise on public health guidelines just as others are doing now to reopen shops and factories. You can already see hints of what it might look like in the proposals to open Austria to German tourists or create “tourists corridors” to Croatia. I have no idea whether and how it will happen but you can clearly see it's a **very high** priority for these countries.

Comment: @Traveller Those are internal Schengen borders, not external. Austria, Croatia and Greece, where togeather with Germany and Switzerland have a low active rate of cases (Germany just under 12%) will probably serve as a *blueprint* on how this can be organized safely. It has not been forgotten that the first major spread in Europe was caused after vacationing in the alps at the end of February. I think that only after regular travel within the Schengen area is safely possible will thoughts be made about it external borders. This will take time.

Comment: Does it matter if the entire country is open or not? The US might be technically a possibility, but only in some states.

Comment: @JonathanReez Parts of coutries being open are fine.

Comment: Surely "being able to be a tourist" should be among the criteria? For if you can freely travel to and stay in e.g. Paris but you are not pemitted to explore the streets, parks, restaurants, cafés, bars, clubs, churches, cathedrals, galleries, museums etc - to do tourism - what is the point?

Comment: For condition 3 see [Where can I find an up-to-date list of COVID-19-related curfews and business closures in different countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155345/1810)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## EU +

*EU+ is loosely used to refer to countries in the EU, European Economic Area, Switzerland, the UK and Schengen Microstates.*

### Pretty Open

*Countries in this section are open to a majority of other European countries*

- **[Austria:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/AUT)** Seamless entry is possible provided the traveler resides in a country with a "stable COVID situation" and has spent the entire 10 previous days in countries with a "stable COVID situation." A list of countries (all EU+) with "stable COVID situations" are listed in the [Entry Ordinance](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/GeltendeFassung.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=20011194) If the traveler has been to other countries within the previous 10 days, quarantine obligations can be lifted with a negative COVID test. [An entry and transit declaration is required.](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Dokumente/BgblAuth/BGBLA_2020_II_372/COO_2026_100_2_1781594.html)
- **[Belgium:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/BEL)** Travel from EU+ countries is generally allowed without quarantine unless the traveler is coming from a ["Red Zone"](https://diplomatie.belgium.be/en). [All persons returning to Belgium or travelling through Belgium, and who are staying at least 48 hours, must fill out a Passenger Locator Form 48 hours before arrival in Belgium.](https://travel.info-coronavirus.be/public-health-passenger-locator-form)
- **[Bulgaria:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/BGR)** Travel from EU+ countries is allowed without restrictions (based on nationality/residency). There is an additional list of non EU+ countries whose citizens can travel to Bulgaria.
- **[Croatia:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/HRV)** Travel from EU+ countries is allowed without restrictions (for EU+ citizens and residents). [All travellers are required to fill out the form available at the EnterCroatia web-page.](https://entercroatia.mup.hr/) Tourists from outside the EU+ can also enter and be exempt from quarantine provided they test negative for COVID either 48 hours before entry. It is also possible to have a COVID test performed after entry but the traveler must isolate until the results of that test are known.
- **[Cyprus:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/CYP)** [Cyprus divides countries into 3 categories A, B and C.](https://cyprusflightpass.gov.cy/en/country-categories) Travelers from category A countries can enter without the need of a COVID test. Travelers from category B may enter with a COVID test completed within 72 hours of departure. Travelers from category B countries may also be tested on arrival in Cyprus if it is not possible to be tested before hand. Travelers from category C countries can not travel to Cyprus for tourism. [Travelers flying to Cyprus must obtain a flight pass within 24 hours prior to departing.](https://cyprusflightpass.gov.cy/)
- **[Czechia:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/CZE)** [Entry is possible from EU+ countries apart from Spain and Romania. Tourism from some non-EU+ countries is also permitted.](https://koronavirus.mzcr.cz/en/list-of-countries-according-to-the-level-of-risk/)
- **[Denmark:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/DNK)** [Unrestricted travel is possible from yellow countries without a need for quarantine.  Some non-EU+ countries are on the list of yellow countries.](https://politi.dk/en/coronavirus-in-denmark/travelling-in-or-out-of-denmark/is-my-country-open-or-banned) In general a country is a yellow country if the rate of infections exceeds 50 per 100 000 over the previous 7 days. The list is updated every Thursday, with decisions taking effect on the forthcoming Saturday at 00.00.
- **[France:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/FRA)**
  [Unrestricted entry is possible from EU+ countries (except the UK) and some non-EU+ countries.](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coronavirus-advice-for-foreign-nationals-in-france/) Quarantine requirements for travelers from the UK are unclear. [A travel certificate is required.](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage) Travel to overseas territories requires a negative COVID test with 72 hours before departure. Travel to some but not all overseas territories is restricted.
- **[Germany:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/DEU)** Unrestricted travel is allowed from EU+ countries so long as the traveler has not been in any [area designated as high risk by the RKI](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html). Regions are generally considered high risk if the rate of new COVID-19 infections exceed 50 per 100 000 over a 7 day period. If coming from a risk area, a 14 day quarantine is required or the traveler must test negative for COVID-19 within 48 prior to departure or within 72 hours of arriving within Germany. Travelers must stay in quarantine until their test result is known. From October 1, it is expected that cancellation of the 14 day quarantine will only be possible after testing negative twice: once on arrival and once 5 days after arrival. The RKI updates the list on a daily basis. [Entry is also possible for some non-EU+ countries.](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/coronavirus/2317268).
- **[Greece:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/GRC)** Unrestricted entry is possible from most but not all EU+ states. [Arrivals must complete a passenger locator form prior to arrival.](https://travel.gov.gr/#/) A negative COVID-19 test is required before arrival for the other EU+ countries. Travel from some non EU+ countries is also possible. Arrivals are subject to random COVID testing.
- **[Italy:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/ITA)** Travel from most EU+ countries is possible though some countries require 14 quarantines and some require negative COVID tests. [Travelers must complete a self-declaration form.](https://www.esteri.it/mae/resource/doc/2020/08/self-declaration_in_case_of_entry_into_italy_from_abroad_-__form_18_8.pdf) Travel from some non-EU+ countries is possible.
- **[Liechtenstein:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/LIE)
- **[Luxembourg:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/LUX)** Travel from EU+ countries is possible without restrictions. Travel from some non-EU+ countries are also possible.
- **[Malta:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/MLT)** [Entry is allowed for most EU+ countries and some non-EU+ countries.](https://deputyprimeminister.gov.mt/en/health-promotion/covid-19/Pages/travel.aspx). For other EU+ countries, a negative COVID test is required 72 hours ahead of entry to be exempt from quarantine. All persons travelling to Malta must complete the [Public Health Travel Declaration](https://mia-prod-s3-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Public-Health-Travel-Declaration-Form-2020_RZA_updated.pdf) and the [Passenger Locator Form](https://mia-prod-s3-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Public-Health-Passenger-Locator-Form.pdf).
- **[Netherlands:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/NLD)** Most tourism from EU+ countries is possible. If coming from a 'red' or 'orange' country, a 10 day quarantine is recommended. Entry from some non EU+ countries is possible. Negative COVID tests are required prior to departing to [some overseas areas](https://www.nederlandwereldwijd.nl/reizen/reisadvies-caribisch-deel-van-het-koninkrijk) of the Netherlands. Other overseas areas are closed to tourists. [Passengers must complete a [screening form](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/documents/publications/2020/07/07/information-for-passengers-flying-to-and-from-the-netherlands) before starting their flight to the Netherlands.
- **[Poland:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/POL)** Travelling from EU+ countries is allowed without restrictions.
- **[Portugal:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/PRT)** Travelling from EU+ countries is allowed without restrictions. Passengers flying to the Madeira or  Azores archipelagos have to present a negative test to COVID-19 carried out within 72 hours prior to departure or they can perform it upon arrival. Travel from some non EU+ countries is possible.

### Only Partially Open

*Countries in this section meet the above criteria in a very limited way*

- **[Estonia:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/EST)** [Entry without quarantine is only possible if coming from a country where the COVID incidence rate is below 16 per 100 000 over the previous 14 days. Otherwise entry is possible from EU+ countries and some non-EU+ countries but the traveler must largely be self-isolated until a second negative COVID test is done 7 days after arrival.](https://vm.ee/en/information-countries-and-self-isolation-requirements-passengers)
- **[Finland:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/FIN)** [Unrestricted entry is only permissible for a few EU+ states and a couple of non-EU+ states.](https://www.raja.fi/current_issues/guidelines_for_border_traffic)
- **[Hungary:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/HUN)** Foreigners are generally not allowed to enter for tourism.  Citizens of Visegrad Group Countries are allowed to enter Hungary if they can show negative coronavirus test not older than five days.
- **[Iceland:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/ISL)** [Passengers arriving in Iceland on and after 19 August 2020 may choose either to submit to two screening tests for COVID-19, separated by five days’ quarantine until the results of the second test are known, or else not to undergo border screening but instead to spend 14 days in quarantine after arrival.](https://www.covid.is/categories/tourists-travelling-to-iceland) [Travelers must submit a registration form prior to arrival.](https://visit.covid.is/) Iceland has lifted travel restrictions for residents of twelve states outside the EU/Schengen Area in line with the decision of EU Member States.
- **[Ireland:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/IRL)** All non-essential overseas travel to and from Ireland should be avoided. Travellers from [green list countries](https://www.gov.ie/en/publication/8868e-view-the-covid-19-travel-advice-list/) may enter Ireland without the need to restrict movements. Passengers from any other location are asked to restrict their movements for 14 days. [Arrivals must submit a passenger locator form.](https://www.gov.ie/en/publication/ab900-covid-19-passenger-locator-form/)
- **[Latvia:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/LVA)** [Those who have arrived from the countries, for which the cumulative number of COVID-19 cases per 100 000 people exceeds 16, must self-isolate for 14
  days upon arrival in Latvia.](https://www.spkc.gov.lv/sites/spkc/files/data_content/28.08.2020-valstu-saraksts-en.pdf) Most but not all EU+ countries fail to meet this criteria. Entry from some non-EU+ countries are possible. [A declaration must be submitted on arrival.](https://www.sam.gov.lv/en/article/questionnaire-be-filled-persons-entering-latvia-using-services-international-carriers)
- **[Lithuania:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/LTU)** A two-week self-isolation requirement is applied to persons arriving from COVID-19 affected countries or in transit through them. Affected countries are those with a coronavirus infection incidence rate exceeding 16 cases per 100,000 inhabitants over the last 14 days.
- **[Norway:](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/NOR) Anyone arriving in Norway from abroad shall be in quarantine for 10 days, with the exception of specified countries in Europe with sufficiently low transmission. [Most EU+ countries are on this list.](https://www.fhi.no/en/op/novel-coronavirus-facts-advice/facts-and-general-advice/travel-advice-COVID19/#areas-with-sufficiently-low-transmission) Exempt countries are countries where there are fewer than 20 confirmed cases per 100 000 inhabitants during the last two weeks (evaluated on a national level), and fewer than 5 per cent positive tests on average per week over the last two weeks.

### Closed

## Non-EU

### Open

### Closed

## Sources

- [Wanderlust](https://www.wanderlust.co.uk/content/coronavirus-travel-updates/)
- [Where can we find frequently updated details about travel/entry restrictions due to Coronavirus (nCoV-19)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154027/where-can-we-find-frequently-updated-details-about-travel-entry-restrictions-due)
- [Re-open EU](https://reopen.europa.eu/en)
- [Where can Canadians travel now?](https://time-to-travel.ca/where-canadians-can-travel-now)
- [IATA COVID-19 Travel Regulations Map](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php)

**Mandatory disclaimer: just because it's *possible* to go somewhere doesn't mean it's a good idea to do so!**

*This answer is a community wiki, so please pitch in with updates with reputable sources, ideally the country's own immigration or health department.*

Comment: Japan might also meet the criteria.

Comment: Italy appears to have announced June 3 as an opening date: https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-italy-decree-idUSKBN22S00P?utm_campaign=trueAnthem%3A+Trending+Content&utm_medium=trueAnthem&utm_source=facebook&fbclid=IwAR2J2gPAUXg3QBoETsn-BrsO4tBzrtPTsGFvxk2cEcZ-Uge14e8p97ArDjg

Comment: US state by state breakdown: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/states-reopen-map-coronavirus.html?smtyp=cur&smid=fb-nytimes&fbclid=IwAR2dP7oMh90nmVP6yWH--fcaRFIBpZPLZWr97gUf-VOO6rgG7BHwbLnHROI

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk This answer is a wiki, please edit it directly.